# Nhibernate Query Over exception on join with invalid value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

```
-- tbl_Region--
ID  DisplayName Description IsUsingLineNumbers    WaitPeriod     FK_StateId
1   UPS            Upstate         0                   10          1
2   DWN            Downstate       1                   20          1
3   OK             Oklahoma        1                   15          2

-- ClientIdentifier-- 
ID  ClientId    FK_RegionId
1   PRCI1             1
2   PRCI2             2
3   PRCI3             3

var clientIdentifier =  session.QueryOver<ClientIdentifier>()
    .Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId).JoinQueryOver(x=>x.Region)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

> This Query is throwing Exception when ClientId    is not valid.  How i
>   can avoid that ?

Comment: What you mean by not valid?

Comment: Means if the value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need deal with nullables properties in the queries you can use this:

```
var query = session.QueryOver<ClientIdentifier>()

if (clientId == null)
    query = query.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.ClientId).IsNull;
else
    query = query.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId);

var clientIdentifier =  query.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Region)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```